# Get values on cells from first column that match a string on a range of cells

Tags: libreoffice-calc

**Hi, I have the following table:**

| Name | Sport 1 | Sport 2 | Sport 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | basketball | baseball |  |
| Luke | skating |  |  |
| John | baseball | football | soccer |
| Peter | soccer | basketball |  |

I want to know how to get the names that have a certain sport in the other columns. For example, if I want to get all the people that play baseball the result would be Mark and John.

I tried with different functions with no success.

Comment: "I tried with different functions" is not something you should write. It provides 0 info. Please provide specific functions that you tried.

Comment: Tried with SEARCH, FIND, HLOOKUP, VLOOKUP, etc.

Comment: No. You should edit the question and post full example of formulas.

Answer (score 2):

Is a "two-tier" solution viable for you?

Per line in the table using an extra column after e.g. "Sport 3"

`=IF(COUNTIF(B2:D2;"baseball")>=1;A2;)`

In the target cell

`=TEXTJOIN(", ";1;A2:A5)`